# "Middle Class"en Español

Tags: traducción

Como se llama la clase socioeconómica "Middle Class" en español? Yo sé que se puede decir "clase media" pero quiero saber si hay otra expresión que tiene el mismo significado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sí, "clase media" es el término apropiado:

http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=HEJVGNxhRDXX2ROkENc8

> ~ media.
>
> 1. f. Conjunto social integrado por personas cuyos ingresos les permiten una vida desahogada en un mayor o menor grado.

No conozco términos equivalentes, pues este es el que se utiliza.

Comment: ¿"Burguesía" tal vez? http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=burgues%C3%ADa Aunque puede sonar un poco anacrónico dependiendo del contexto.

Comment: en historia yo he visto que hasta se distingue alta burguesía, burguesía media y baja burguesía